# Kali-linux rebooting Itself within 10 seconds of boot

Tags: linux, boot, kali-linux, reboot, acpi

I installed kali linux on my computer, but it reboots itself about 10 seconds after turning it on whether I login or not , no matter how much I searched for a solution from the Internet, I couldn't find a solution to the problem or someone who had the same problem as me. So far I tried :

1. I tried formatting my computer,
2. I tried logging in with live boot ,
3. I reset the bios
4. I also tried reinstalling kali,
5. I tried to run windows memory diagnostic on my computer but no error occured,

Note: I have no problems with windows.

[ACPI errors on boot screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAILc.jpg)

I tried to boot by typing acpi=off in the boot parameters on the bootloader screen. Then the screen stuck on the boot loader screen.

My computer information:

```
Hp omen 15
Ryzen 7 5800h
RTX3060 
16gb ram 
512 samsung ssd
```

Comment: Try with Ubuntu

Comment: And check this answer: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5361/101265

Comment: Did you set Grub up properly during Kali installation?  That is necessary. Try installing Kali as a virtual machine to learn it. I am working in Kali here.